# PTIJ: does fasting on Ta'anis Esther give us reward as if we celebrated 2 Purims? (similar to Yom Kippur)

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The gemara in [Berachos 8b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.8b.3?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) teaches us:

> כל האוכל ושותה בתשיעי מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו מתענה תשיעי ועשירי
>
> One who eats and drinks on the ninth day of Tishrei in preparation for the fast the next day, it's as if he fasted on both the ninth and the tenth of Tishrei.

Ie that one who eats alot on Erev Yom Kippur it's as if they fasted 2 days and get credit/ rewarded for doing as such.

**Now:**

1) Since we say that Yom Kippur is "like" Purim- ie יום  "**כ**"פורים

2) and Purim has a *din* of "[ונהפוך הוא](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.9.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)"(switching around/opposite) namely, switch around Yom Kippur's day of eating ➡️ Fast, to Purim's fast ➡️ then day of eating

**So...**

Can we assume that whomever fasts on Ta'anis Esther it's as if they celebrated/ get credit for two Purims?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: What is this “day like Purim” nonsense? We have a [Gezeirah Shavah connecting the two](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55200/9682)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the double reward due to eating on the ninth day of Tishrei is because it directly enables the person to fast on the tenth, hence if fasting today (*Tannit Esther*) enables one to drink double (and perhaps see double) then yes, double reward in the bag!

Answer (score 0):

Whether you realize it or not, most people actually do fast two days!

There is a rule - "Part of the day is considered as if it were the whole day."

The halacha is that one should not break the fast until after Megillah reading is over.

So, technically, one doesn't even need to go to the "as if" aspect. One actually does fast on Purim itself.

Comment: Not when Taanis Esther is on the Thursday before Purim, and not in walled cities.

Comment: @Meir Well, then, there's a carry over. Who says that the days have to be contiguous? Re the walled cities - Trump was right. And, the Israelis actually got someone else to pay for it!